# root user has no access to RDS MYSql instance

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-rds

My project is hosted in a linux box with RDS MySql backend. The root user does not have access to the RDS instance and a custom user 'Prod' alone has access to this RDS instance. When I try to do:

```
mysql -u root -h myhost.amazon.com
```

I get to see the below error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'10.0.6.124' (using password: NO)
```

How to add 'root' user to the MySql RDS instance? Can it be done through the AWS console? Pls guide.

Answer (score 0):

> (using password: NO)

You're not passing in the password (which you've set during RDS setup) for the `root` user. Add the `-p` option to have `mysql` prompt you for it.

Comment: I passed the -p parameter and it prompted for password. When hit blank and enter I still see the same issue

Comment: Yes, you need to pass in the password you've set.